# How to run windows batch file containing OpenSSL encrypt file command from a Windows Service application

Tags: windows, service, openssl

We would like to make some Postgres databases backups from a windows service application, using OpenSSL app to encrypt those files. To accomplish that we use a batch file, containing that command lines. If we do it in two steps, first we make the backup file and after that we want to encrypt it or even when we include in Postgres "pg_dump" instructions it doesn't work, I presume because the service app is running as SYSTEM. If I run the same application as desktop mode it works fine.

Is there any workaround that can help us to do that?

Thank you. Regards.

Comment: Did you get any error message when it didn't work?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi, so I removed the tag.  Please do not randomly add tags that do not apply to your question. Tags have meaning and purpose here, so use only the ones that are actually relevant. Also, *it doesn't work* is not a useful problem description. How **specifically** does it *not work*?

Comment: If I add a pipeline to catch the result, the process hang. If not, it doesn't raise any error and as result I have just my backup file.